# Get a pixels/units relation with opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es, view, pixel, units-of-measurement

I am introducing me on Opengl ES and I am able draw textures with vertex an move it on the screen.

But I can't get a relation between pixels and units. For example:

I want to draw a 64x64 texture, repeated in  all the width of the screen, if the width of the screen is 640, means that the texture will repeat itself 10 times, how can I do that?

I have really searched on the web, but I couldn't found anything, which can help me.

Using this:

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f,100.0f);
```

I can "control" (I think) the size of the texture, with change the second parameter 45.0f, but I doesn't have any idea, which operation to do in this function in order to get the value of the width of the screen to set the number of units of the screen and later using them correctly.

```
 gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f,-0.0f);
```

This is used to get the right view of the textures, well, that is what I understand.

I really don't know if I am going to the right way.

Comment: Save your remaining neurons by starting with a [decent tutorial](http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) on OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a bit to understand the openGL world. You may try 
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

or any other. Any iPhone tutorial works too. You should try using an orthographic projection (or an identity matrix projection) to make what you want, but trying to do something like using the screen pixels as units in openGL is quite ugly.